# Can hemostatics like QuikClot and Celox get into blood stream and cause embolic clots?

Tags: medical-science

From what I understand products like Quikclot and Celox are used by the US military in first aid kits. The products are used to stop severe bleeding. While [some studies](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21496135) indicate that these products might not actually work better than using direct pressure with standard gauze, [other studies](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19741385) have shown that they do help in controlling bleeding.

The first generation of QuikClot [generated so much](http://www.z-medica.com/healthcare/How-QuikClot-Works/QuikClot-1st-and-2nd-Generation.aspx) heat that it caused burns, but the newer version does not have this problem. And there have been other problems. The military supposedly stopped using the power version of these product in part because the powder would blow in peoples faces and cause problems. Now they use a gauze impregnated with this powder/granulates.

On [this forum](http://www.firehouse.com/forums/t116447/#post1200286) ([and other places](http://cqb-team.com/cqbforum/viewtopic.php?p=4636&sid=f1ae12fc6bfa9aa6bc13e07a9ac263e4#p4636)) the claim is made that "*dumping the powder on a torn blood vessel possibly send small clots around the cardio vascular system?*" and "*celox works well but there is some studies that show the they flakes were getting into the blood stream and causing more problems.*"

I am interested in knowing if this claim is true. That is, is it true that the powder from these products can get into the blood stream and cause problems other places in the body?

Are there really any studies suggesting this?

Comment: Probably useful to note that in a soldier's first aid kit, the line of reasoning could very easily be something along the lines of "If I use this, he *might* develop clots that *might* cause long term issues... But if I *don't* use this, chances are he'll bleed to death in the next five minutes. Stabilize him now, worry about long term effects when he's evac'ed to a hospital."

Comment: @Nospam, if clots get into an artery, they go to the end organ eg. fingers/legs, or a vein, they go to the lungs.  They can't get into the brain without a hole in the heart present with right to left shunting eg. patent atrial septal defect.

Comment: @Shadur Agreed. When we received first-aid training for Quikclot, it was stressed that it was for *serious* bleeding only, to be used only if death by blood loss was likely.